# Hosting NamedPipe WCF on Win7 IIS 7.5 EndpointNotFoundException

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, iis

I am trying to create WCF NamedPipe in win7 with IIS 7.5.

1. In IIS Manager right click, and create WebSite named "TestWCFWithNamedPipe"
2. Right click my WebSite "TestWCFWithNamedPipe" -> select Edit bindings

   ```
   Type:http 
   Host Name:sample.localdev.net 
   Port:80 
   Address:*

   Type:net.pipe 
   Binding informations:*
   ```
3. In Advanced settings set the value for Enabled Protocol as "http,net.pipe"
4. In My WebSite "TestWCFWithNamedPipe" Web Application Project

`web.config`:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>

<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="DefaultBehavior">
                <serviceDebug />
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="SampleWcfLib.SampleWcfObj">
            <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/Sample" binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="" contract="SampleWcfInterfaceLib.ISampleWcfObj" />
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

`TestClient.exe` code is following

```
string address = "net.pipe://localhost/Sample";
NetNamedPipeBinding binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding(); 
EndpointAddress ep = new EndpointAddress(address);
ISampleWcfObj channel = ChannelFactory<ISampleWcfObj>.CreateChannel(binding, ep);
string result = channel.Ping("Test");
```

And I run `TestClient.exe`, and I get an exception:

> There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/Sample that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

I have checked Win7 Service status:

```
Net.Pipe Listener Adapter   Started
Net.Tcp Listener Adapter    Started
```

I have done all settings for WCF.

Why do I still get the `EndpointNotFoundException` error message ?

Comment: You set up your website as sample.localdev.net in IIS. Shouldn't you then use that address?

Comment: I use net.pipe mode, is net.pipe need "sample.localdev.net" address?
So I should use "net.pipe://sample.localdev.net/Sample"? I've tried, It is Wrong!

Comment: I would give it a go.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the name of your tcp binding if you have a look in your XSD file.
It will be on the bottom of your file and it will look like this

```
<wsdl:service name="PersonService">
   <wsdl:port name="NetNamedPipeBinding_IPersonContract" binding="tns:NetNamedPipeBinding_IPersonContract">
        <soap12:address location="net.pipe://wcftestpipe/WcfTest/PersonService.svc/test"/>
        <wsa10:EndpointReference>
             <wsa10:Address>net.pipe://wcftestpipe/WcfTest/PersonService.svc/test</wsa10:Address>
        </wsa10:EndpointReference>
   </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Afther that you propably get a security exeception that will say you don't have the right credentials. You can set your binding security mode to NONE in your web.config of your WCF service and app.config of your Client.

```
<bindings>
    <netNamedPipeBinding>
      <binding>
        <security mode="None"/>
      </binding>
    </netNamedPipeBinding>
</bindings>
```

Hope this helps